# SQL Server : Multiple Date Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me with this SQL Server query :

My logic is: `Date now = (date1 OR date2 OR date3)`

```
SELECT * 
FROM [HPM_QC_PCard]  
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 1) = (CONVERT(DATE, [PRIMRY], 1) OR 
                                   CONVERT(DATE, [AUTO_UT_DATE], 1) OR 
                                   CONVERT(DATE, [XRAY_FIN_DATE], 1) OR 
                                   CONVERT(DATE, [HYDROTEST_DATE], 1) OR 
                                   CONVERT(DATE, [FINAL_INS_DATE], 1) )
```

Comment: Depending on data distribution and available indexes, UNION ALL approach migth be more performant than ORs.

Comment: @dean a UNION ALL would return unwanted duplicate rows if there are more matches

Comment: @t-clausen.dk sure, I meant UNION, thx for the correction. and another thing: these CONVERTS will probably unSARG, so indexes or not doesn't really matter here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sql [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

```
SELECT * 
FROM [HPM_QC_PCard] 
WHERE 
   CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 1) 
      IN (CONVERT(DATE, [PRIMRY], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [AUTO_UT_DATE], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [XRAY_FIN_DATE], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [HYDROTEST_DATE], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [FINAL_INS_DATE], 1)
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) operator.

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery
>   or a list.

---

Sample in your case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [HPM_QC_PCard] 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE(), 1) IN
       (
          CONVERT(DATE, [PRIMRY], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [AUTO_UT_DATE], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [XRAY_FIN_DATE], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [HYDROTEST_DATE], 1),
          CONVERT(DATE, [FINAL_INS_DATE], 1)  
       )
```